# Saving image/GIF using a GPIO button

Tags: pitft

I'm running tv.giphy.com on my RPi, which shows random (or not) GIFs in full screen mode. I run the website in Cromium's kiosk mode. I have a PiTFT with 4 incorporated buttons and I would like to use one of these buttons to automatically save the image/GIF that I'm looking at on RPI's memory (SD card).

Could you help me/direct me to some documentation as to how to set up PiTFT's buttons? I can't seem to find anything relevant.

I just bought my first RPI less than 2 weeks ago and I'm a complete noob, but I'm getting really excited about all the possibilities :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the seller of the PiTFT say?

Comment: And can you add a link to your screen? If it's a 'real' PiTFT (from Adafruit) then you can find the documentation in the device description and on the Adafruit learn pages.

Comment: Of course, it's the Adafruit 2.2" LCD screen: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-2-pitft-hat-320-240-primary-display-for-raspberry-pi/overview

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the buttons are connected to GPIO pins directly, just try creating Button objects on every pin and seeing which one's state changes when you press a button:

```
from gpiozero import ButtonBoard
from signal import pause

buttons = ButtonBoard(*range(2, 28))

for btn in buttons:
    btn.when_pressed = lambda b: print(b.pin)

pause()
```

(note this is Python 3 code)

Now press one of the buttons and you should see its pin number printed out e.g. `GPIO2`.

When you know which pin numbers to use, create Button objects on those pins, e.g:

```
from gpiozero import Button

btn_a = Button(2)
btn_b = Button(3)
btn_c = Button(4)
btn_d = Button(5)
```

There's a chance they're wired pull-down, and the pressed/released logic would be reversed, so you'd use `Button(4, pull_up=False)`.

See the [gpiozero Button documentation](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#button) and [recipes](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. Being a complete novice, I assume from your message that I need to install the Python 3 GPIO package. I will have some spare time this weekend so I will let you know how it works. Thanks so much again. Btw, the buttons are indeed connected directly to the GPIO, this being the Adafruit 2.2" LCD display, with 4 buttons. I found a link explaining which GPIO's are connected to the buttons, but I couldn't figure out which button goes to which GPIO specifically, so will try to find out this weekend.

Comment: This GPIO library is pre-installed in Raspbian desktop. If you don't have it, the installation instructions are here: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html

Comment: Every time I try to run the following Python command: 'buttons = ButtonBoard(*range(2, 28))', it gives me the following error: Failed to add edge detection. What does that mean? I tried troubleshooting this using this script: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-gpiozero/issues/687#issuecomment-435620598 , but  get the same error. Could someone direct me to the right answer? Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, I'm not using the GPIO pins for anything else but the PiTFT display

Comment: Those comments were outdated, the RPi.GPIO update has been released. Just make sure you're full updated: `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: In which case how do I modify your code above using RPi.GPIO so that I can see which GPIO's are being used by each button?